# Uso de & junto a operadores e funções em PHP

Tags: php, operadores

Qual o significado do uso de `&` junto de operadores e funções em PHP? Verifiquei em algumas bibliotecas ([exemplo](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html)) e funções este uso (tenho conhecimento do uso junto a variáveis tem relação com a passagem de ponteiros).

```
$browser = &new SimpleBrowser();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Este é o [operador de referência](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). Ela não é muito comum em PHP. Ele causa efeito colateral e nem todos estão cientes da implicação disto. Embora o funcionamento é muito semelhante ao dos objetos em geral que são referências por padrão.

Usando este operador você cria um alias para uma variável. Então uma variável que recebe uma referência na verdade está recendo um endereço para outra variável.

Em alguns casos ele pode ser útil em parâmetros. É uma forma do código retornar resultados extras já que o normal é uma função ou método retornar apenas um valor. Com a referência você pode passar um valor que automaticamente será armazenado no local onde ele se originou, ou seja, na variável que ele estava. Uma alteração no parâmetro local da função alterará a variável usada para passá-lo. Então funciona como um retorno.

Note que alguns tipos isto é o normal. *Arrays* e objetos são por referência. Os chamados tipos primitivos é que precisam deste operador para mudar o comportamento já que o normal destes tipos é que os valores sejam copiados e torna-se independentes.

Em alguns casos pode ser útil também em iterações:

```
foreach($obj as $key => &$value)
    $value = 1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Reference.php).

Desta forma alterando a variável `$value` você está alterando o elemento do objeto.

Aparentemente o uso de `& new` é um legado da versão 4 e não deve mais ser usado. De fato não faz sentido o seu uso porque o `new` cria uma referência. Nem vou procurar melhores explicações porque o 4 usava isto, afinal ninguém deveria estar usando ele mais. O importante é que agora não precisa mais. Acredito que era obrigado por OOP no 4 era bem gambiarra e começou a fazer parte da linguagem de uma forma minimamente decente na versão 5.

Comment: Mas qual o significado da utilização junto com o operador `new`?(no link postado tem o uso) o mesmo?

Comment: Estou tentando descobrir, isto é muito estranho para mim. Mesmo p/ PHP  :)

Comment: Isso ai era usado no php4 se não me engano.

Comment: A orientação a Objeto do PHP 4 era uma gambiarra pura :\

Answer (score 5):

Isso se trata do **Operador de Refência**.

De acordo com o PHP

> Referências, em PHP, significa acessar o mesmo conteúdo de variável através de vários nomes

Veja um exemplo:

```
$a = 1;

$b = $a;

$a = 2;

var_dump($a, $b); // a => 2, b => 1
```

Agora um exemplo com o operador de referência:

```
$a = 1
$b =& $a;
$a = 2;

var_dump($a, $b)/ // a= > 2, b => 2
```

Ou seja, `$b` aponta para o valor de `$a`. Ele não tem um valor independente, mas ele aponta para o local da memória onde o valor de `$a` foi salvo.

No caso das funções, O operador `&` pode ser utilizado de duas formas:

- [Passagem por referência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php)
- [Retorno por referência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.return.php).

Vou dar um exemplo de passagem por referência nas funções:

```
$meuValor = [1, 2, 3];

    function my_function(&$var, $add){
       $var[] = $add;
    }

    my_function($meuValor, 6);

    print_($meuValor); // [1, 2, 3, 6];
```

Veja que o valor de `$meuValor` foi alterado, sem o `return` dentro da função e sem a reatribuição da mesma pelo retorno de `my_function`.

Isso acontece porque `$var` passa ser referência da variável passada por parâmetro; ou seja, a variável `$meuValor`.

A utilização no Operador `new` foi desencorajada, e, se não me engano, gera um erro `E_STRICT` ao tentar fazer.

Isso ocorria nas versões anteriores ao PHP 5.

Nas versões novas do PHP, os objetos são passados por referência por padrão.

Answer (score 5):

O operador `&` tem algumas funções atualmente é usado como operador de referência como as duas respostas explica bem e também é usando em funções anônimas.

O exemplo do link é bem peculiar ele é herança do php4 onde o suporte(**adaptação**) à orientação a objetos começou uma serie de coisas não tinha implicações como por exemplo todos os membros da classe serem públicos e o `& =`. Os exemplos foram retirados do [manual antigo](http://doc.php.net/archives/php4/)  sessão Classes and Objects(PHP 4) > References inside the constructor

[**Exemplo**](https://3v4l.org/bgBVS), roda no php4 em outra versões.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    function Foo($name) {
        // create a reference inside the global array $globalref
        global $globalref;//<--- variável global WTF que tenta exemplicar a diferença
        //do new e do &=
        $globalref[] = &$this;
        // set name to passed value
        $this->setName($name);
        // and put it out
        $this->echoName();
    }

    function echoName() {
        echo "<br />", $this->name;
    }

    function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
?>
```

O código abaixo tenta demonstrar o uso `new` que apenas retorna uma cópia do objeto e suas variáveis e do `& =` que retorna a referência, que em miudos significa que algumas atribuições podem não 'sincronizar' os valores das variáves/membros da classe/gambiarra como 'esperado'.

**Exemplo 1**

Aqui mostra que tudo está ok o comportamento 'esperado' acontece pois nenhuma modificação foi feita.

```
<?php
$bar1 = new Foo('set in constructor');
$bar1->echoName();
$globalref[0]->echoName();

/* output:
set in constructor
set in constructor
set in constructor */

$bar2 =& new Foo('set in constructor');
$bar2->echoName();
$globalref[1]->echoName();

/* output:
set in constructor
set in constructor
set in constructor */
?>
```

**Exemplo 2**

Aqui sim mostra a diferença que `$this->name` e `$globalref[0]` em `$bar1` não são a mesma coisa pois o valor foi cópiado, equanto `$bar2` são a mesma coisa porque por causa do operador de referência `& =`.

```
<?php
// now we will change the name. what do you expect?
// you could expect that both $bar1 and $globalref[0] change their names...
$bar1->setName('set from outside');

// as mentioned before this is not the case.
$bar1->echoName();
$globalref[0]->echoName();

/* output:
set from outside
set in constructor */

// let us see what is different with $bar2 and $globalref[1]
$bar2->setName('set from outside');

// luckily they are not only equal, they are the same variable
// thus $bar2->name and $globalref[1]->name are the same too
$bar2->echoName();
$globalref[1]->echoName();

/* output:
set from outside
set from outside */
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer, eu nunca tinha visto em manuais atuais este uso.

Comment: Só baixando o manual velho :P da uma olhada hehe. @ricardo

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um operador de referencia que permite ao inves de se trabalhar com o valor da variavel trabalhar com o seu endereço, vide exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
   $a = &$b;
   // aqui $a e $b apontam para a mesma variável. 
?>
```

Logo $a e $b sãoiguais aqui, porque $a e $b apontam para o mesmo lugar.

A mesma sintaxe pode ser utilizada com funções que retornam referências e com o operador new (a partir do PHP 4.0.4):

```
$bar = & new fooclass();
$foo = & find_var ($bar);
```

Porém vale lembrar que a NÃO utilização do operador & causará a cópia do objeto. Se você utiliza $this em classes, ele operará na instância atual do objeto. A assimilação sem & irá copiar a instância (o objeto em si) e $this irá operar na cópia, podendo não ser esse procedimento sempre desejável. Normalmente você precisará trabalhar com uma instância única, seja por motivos de performance ou de consumo de memória.

Outro uso seria para fazer alterações dentro de objetos de um foreach ex:

```
foreach($questions as &$question){

}
```

*Naturalmente as modificações em `$question` não existirá no objeto do array `$question`.