# Qual o objetivo do & no PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$a = '1';
$b = &$a;
$b = "2$b";
echo $a.", ".$b;
```

Saída:

```
21, 21
```

Percebi que não há nenhuma atribuição a variável `$a` a não ser pelo fato de que `$b = &$a` usando o `&`, que no final, o resultado é alterado. Não entendi muito bem, por isso me questiono:

O que significa o `&` para esta situação? Qual seria o objetivo? E em que momento isso é usado?

Comment: Para que ao invés de usar o valor a manipulação de variavel use como "referencia", ou seja ao copiar o valor para outra "variavel" será possivel manipular a variavel original através da outra (mais ou menos isto) :)

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51209/uso-de-junto-a-operadores-e-funções-em-php

Comment: As respostas dos colegas estão ótimas, apenas sugiro ler a documentação do [Objetos e referências](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.references.php) do PHP, para elucidar dúvidas.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Mal posso ver seus movimentos.

Comment: Relacionado [Referência de argumentos pode ser prejudicial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57741/3635)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A diferença em utilizar ou não o & é que, com o & é feito uma referência, você estará utilizando a mesma variável em memória, mesmo que o nome da variável seja diferente, se alterar uma, altera a outra e vice versa.

Sem o & você faz uma cópia da variável, se alterar alguma das duas, uma não afetará a outra, são independentes e apontam para lugares diferentes em memória.

```
<?php

$a = '1'; // $a = '1'
$b = &$a; // $b = $a = 1
$b = "2$b"; // $b = "2($a)" = "21"
echo $a.", ".$b; // Como $b faz referência a $a e vice versa, $b foi alterado para 21 na linha acima, logo a saída será igual, 21 para ambos os valores
```

Answer (score 4):

O `&` serve para atribuir ou modificar uma variável por referência.

```
$b = &$a
```

Significa que toda vez que `$a` for alerado `$b` terá o mesmo valor pois valor de `$b` aponta sempre para `$a`. Caso o valor `$b` mude `$a` terá o mesmo valor.

Como fica interpretação desse código:

```
$a = '1';
$b = &$a; //ambas as variáveis tem valor 1
$b = "2$b"; // $b recebe o número 2 seguido do seu valor anterior ou seja 1 e modifica/sobrescreve o valor `$a`
echo $a.", ".$b; //
```